# What is the special LEGO Movie 1x1 element shown in the Channel 4 documentary 'Inside LEGO at Christmas'?

Tags: part-identification, the-lego-movie

I recently watched the UK Channel 4 documentary '[Inside LEGO At Christmas](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/inside-lego-at-christmas)' and in it, one of the employees of [Bright Bricks](http://bright-bricks.com/) showed a tall 1x1 element that he described as a brick that Lego came up with for The Lego Movie set.

It can be [viewed on YouTube here @7:17](https://youtu.be/Kj3VjzAHvOI?t=7m17s)

- Is this element included in any commercially available sets?
- Is it indexed on Bricklink?

I have done several web searches for other references and also searched Bricklink but have been unable to find any other information about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Piece of Resistance
[image]

can be found in [11 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=15444&in=S)

[bricklink link](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=15444&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

Answer (score 0):

[The piece that Syberion linked to in his answer](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=15444&idColor=5#T=C&C=5) isn't entirely correct. While the Piece of Resistance in the *LEGO Movie* sets is *similar* to the one seen in the movie, the actual piece didn't have the square hole. (That was used in the sets based on the movie so you didn't need to actually glue the piece to the minifigure!)

It doesn't look like a "real" 1x1x2 piece has been used in any sets yet. [1x1x3](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?id=123119) ones have, and obviously 1x1x1 ones, but not the in-between size.

Comment: I think the accepted answer is technically correct according to the details of my question since I was trying to identify the actual element shown in the C4 show which did have a hole, as it was the commercial available element. However, I take your point that the actual element from the Movie does not have a hole and is not available in any sets. Thanks for the extra info.